# Download Html5 canvas on click action

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, buttonclick

I am working on Html5 canvas.

Currently I am downloading image on right click and selecting an option of **save image**

Now i want to include **DOWNLOAD** button that can save and downloads the Canvas as an Image.

My code is :

```
 var download = document.getElementById('img-download');
   download.addEventListener('click', prepareDownload, false);

  function prepareDownload() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("memecanvas");
    document.getElementById("memecanvas").src = canvas.toDataURL();

    Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
  }
```

This simply enables to download it via right click.
Please help me how to deal with this on Button click action.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eli Grey has created a nice shim for browsers that don't implement the Blob which is required to save html5 canvas to disk with eventing: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Answer (score 0):

Just create a button, give it an ID of, say, "download-button".

Then instead of adding the click event handler to the img-download element, assign it to the button using it's ID.